# Configure a non-JNDI datasource for pentaho

Tags: java, dependency-injection, pentaho

We are running Pentaho reports from a tomcat based java app using a datasource configured in JNDI as per the pentaho instructions [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Creating+a+Data+Source+for+Tomcat).

Is there a way to configure Pentaho to accept a non-JNDI based DataSource programatically?